# Calculate probability to win in a contest?

Tags: probability

The probability to win contest $A$ is $0.6$, and for contest $B$ it's $0.8$, then what's the probability to win at least one of them?

If I sum the probabilities I get $1.4$ which doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: **Boldly** assuming independence, the probability of losing both is $(1-0.6)\cdot(1-0.8)=0.08$, so for winning at least one it is $0.92$.

Comment: I think this should be tagged [tag:probability], not [tag:calculus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assume the events are independent of each other, you shouldn't be summing the probabilities of winning each individual contest. Note that the probability of winning **both** $A$ and $B$ is $0.6\times 0.8 = 0.48$. Then the probability of winning $A$ and *losing* $B$ is $0.6\times (1-0.8) = 0.6 \times 0.2 = 0.12$, and the probability of winning $B$ and *losing* $A$ is $0.8\times (1-0.6) = 0.8\times 0.4 = 0.32$. Summing these three probabilities we end up with $0.92$, or $92\%$ chance of winning at least one contest.

Alternatively, note that the only way to **not** win at least one of the contests is to *lose* both of them. The probability of that happening is $(1-0.8)\times (1-0.6) = 0.2\times 0.4 = 0.08$. So we subtract $1-0.08 = 0.92$, to get the same answer as before.

Comment: But why what I did is wrong, when we allowed to sum and when not?

Comment: @user128250 Think about the event space you're in. Let's denote the outcome of winning at $X$ by $W_X$, and losing by $L_X$. So then the event space is $\{ (W_A,W_B), (W_A,L_B),(L_A,W_B),(L_A,L_B)\}$. These are the **only** four options you have, and the sum of their respective probabilities is $1$ (try to come up with a different outcome if you don't believe me). One thing you'll note is that $W_A$ on its own is **not** an element of this set. This is because the question asks of you to consider the outcomes of both contests, not just one of them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't there any example of when we sum probabilities?

Comment: @user128250 Try rereading my answer: in fact, we sum probabilities there. In general, we sum the probabilities of two outcomes $x$ and $y$ (from the same sample space) when we want to find the probability of $x$ **or** $y$ (or both - this is an inclusive or) happening. Using the sample space I established in my first comment, we find the probability of $(W_A,W_B)$ or $(W_A,L_B)$ or $(L_A,W_B)$ happening by adding them all up. Please consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: but again, according to what you said I can sum the two I suggested and get 1.4 still you didn't show what is wrong with this...

Comment: @user128250 Because you can't add probabilities from different event spaces.

Comment: but why those which you added are from the same space while my suggestion isn't?

Comment: @user128250 See my first comment where I've explicitly shown the event space. As far as the outcome of contest $A$ is concerned, the event space is $\{ Win_A, Lose_A\}$, with $P(Win_A)=0.6$ and $P(Lose_A)=0.4$. But your question concerned the outcomes of **both** contests, not just $A$, and not just $B$, so the event space is as stated in my first comment: $\{(Win_A,Win_B),(Win_A,Lose_B),(Lose_A,Win_B),(Lose_A,Lose_B)\}$.